# np.power (raised to power 2) of matrix is not resulting in elements^2

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to square the elements of a matrix m in python using either m**2 or np.power(m**2). The result is that some of the elements are squared whereas some are not

Unfortunately I can't seem to replicate the problem in a test case and the matrix is large, but taking a snapshot showing parts of the first and last few rows will helpfully highlight the issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLLLD.png)

It seems like some of the elements are factorised or something? I'd appreciate it if someone could explain this behaviour for me.

Comment: Also I think you mean `np.power(m, 2)`

Comment: no text as images please!

Answer (score 3):

The element in your matrix are of type 8-bit unsigned integer (`uint8`) which means they are restricted between 0 and 255. So `(252**2) % 256 = 16`

You can change your array type using:

```
m = m.astype(np.uint16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements of your `np.array` are indeed sqaured.

The type of your array is `uint8`, which makes all arythmetical operations modulo 256.

```
>>> 252 ** 2 % 256
16
```